# Error by reunite Multiple tar.gz Files of Certain Size

Tags: c#, split, tar.gz

Does anyone have experience with splitting tar.gz and what could have gone wrong here and why some files are damaged during splitting? I split one "testFile.tar.gz" file into parts not larger than 2 GB.
For example
testFile.tar.gz.001
testFile.tar.gz.002
testFile.tar.gz.003. I split the testFile.tar.gz file so that the input stream reads the data from testFile.tar.gz. and the output stream is written this data first in testFile.tar.gz.000 until it reaches the size of 2 GB, after this it is written in testFile.tar.gz001 and so on. I try to re-unite all parts with 7-zip. I mark all parts, then right-click the mouse and "7-Zip>unpack here".
I get the following error message

1. unexpected end of data,
   the data cannot be opened as a [gzip] archive,

   the data was opened as a [tar] archive
2. Data error: [path of corrupted file]

Comment: I have split tar archives before.  I simply uses split then used cat to combine the files.  Do not use 7-zip to recombine.

Comment: It seems to me that you are talking about split and cat commands for Linux. I forgot to say. I write a program on Windows for splitting large tar.gz archive. With 7-Zip I want to check if the parts are recombine again

Comment: There is no real differences.  To make sure you split and recombine work all you have to do is compare the original gz with the final.  You can use an binary compare tool like Beyond Compare.  All split does (either linux or windows) is divide the bit file into little files.  In windows you can just combine the files together using append.  Once the compare works than there is no reason 7-Zip will also work.